# RAM PerformanceCounter problems

Tags: .net, windows-vista, permissions, performancecounter, bsod

My code:

```
var list = new LinkedList<int>();
var ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
while (true)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000 * 1000; i++) list.AddLast(0);
    Console.WriteLine(ramCounter.NextValue());
}
```

Questions:

1. The documentation seems to say I can use a PerformanceCounter only as an **Administrator**, but I ran my application as a **Standard User** and it worked. Can I rely on that?
2. I consistently get **OutOfMemoryException** when about 200 MB RAM remain, **why**? It can't be due to fragmentation because I allocate an int at a time. Also, it can't be because of addressability issues, as I'm already way above 2GB (the exception gets thrown when 2.8 out of my 3GB are taken). The numbers output by the test app were verified with a Task Manager window running at the side.
3. Once I got a BSOD when the test app was running and about 400 MB were remaining. Any hints as to what could possibly cause this? I'll run a check for RAM integrity, anything else? Should I be careful with calling `PerformanceCounter.NextValue()` in a loop, or something? Note, that's the first time I get a BSOD on this PC.
4. At some points in the program execution, I get big delays. E.g. when I start at 1 GB free RAM, when I get to 700 MB the app freezes for 1 sec, then at about 400 MB it freezes for about 4 sec. Why is this? Because the OS needs to swap out disk caches to free up memory, or something?

**Note:** Why am I doing this? Well, I want my memory-intensive app to detect when 5 MB RAM remain, and alert the user with "Memory is low, please close other programs and come back, or this program will fail."

Comment: Unless you have some reference to back up your assertions that it can't be fragmentation or addressability issues you shouldn't rule those out.

Comment: Why did you make this a community wiki?

Comment: Amuck: well, no matter how badly fragmented the memory is, space for one int (or a couple, accounting for LinkedList overhead) will always be found. Also I don't see how it can be addressability related, considering my 32-bit Windows can address memory up to 4GB, and I'm operating below three.

Comment: Actually you can't expect to be able to allocate another int. The CLR doesn't allocate single ints with the OS as that would be highly ineffective. Instead it allocates in bigger chucks called segments. So your single int may trigger a much bigger allocation.

Comment: It is correct that you can address 4GB of memory, but typically about 256-512 MB of this is used by your graphics adapter which maps a significant amount of memory if the 4 GB address space. Other device may also take up space. See hardware manager for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't address all your questions, but here goes

2) Are you on 32 or 64 bit Windows? It sounds like you're running a large address aware process with access to 3 GB (i.e. on 32 bit Windows). In any case you have to keep in mind that memory is allocated in chucks of various sizes and your heap usage is not the only source. The CLR itself has numerous structures, each thread has a stack and so on. In any case, you can't really expect to be able to use exactly 3 GB,

3) BSOD is due to driver or kernel errors. AFAIK your application cannot cause BSOD, so this is most likely unrelated.

4) If you use a lot of memory the GC will have a hard time keeping up. As user threads are suspended while certain parts of GC is in progress this will slow down your application significantly.

Comment: I'm using a 32-bit Windows - could you elaborate how this can be a problem? I didn't get your explanation. Also, even if I can't expect to be able to use exactly 3GB, I CAN expect PerformanceCounter to return near-zero when I'm out of memory, right? As to GC, I guess that's correct, but it's a bit of a downer to have GC eat up huge processing time for little reason.

Comment: Memory allocation is a complex matter. I recommend that you take a look at Mark Russinovich's series on the matter at http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx as this is not really a subject to be discussed in comments.

Comment: The GC is running because you're using and holding on to a lot of memory. That is how GC works. As it rearranges memory, it needs to suspend user threads to avoid compromising state.